# Nagios check_logs.pl gives OK even with Error in log file

Tags: logging, nagios

I am using `check_logs.pl` file of Nagios to check for error in a log file for any errors in puppet run. Errors are logged in a file `/var/log/puppet/error.log`. The config file is

```
/usr/local/nagios/custom/check_puppet.cfg
```

contents of the file are:

```
[root@prod nagios] cat /usr/local/nagios/custom/check_puppet.cfg
$seek_file_template='/var/log/puppet/$log_file.puppet-agent.check_log.seek';

@log_files =
  (
    {
      'file_name'    => '/var/log/puppet/error.log',
      'reg_exp'  => '(Could not send report:|Could not retrieve file metadata for |Could not retrieve catalog from remote server|Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run|Error 500 on SERVER:)',
    },
  );
```

The problem is I am getting OK irrespective of the contents of the error file.i.e The log file contains error still the output is OK.
Any ideas why this is happening??.

Contents of error file:

```
[root@prod nagios] cat /var/log/puppet/error.log
Dec 25 11:13:12 prod puppet-agent: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Dec 25 11:33:53 prod puppet-agent: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find data item internalrepo::prod::repo_server in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at /etc/puppet/modules/prod-modules/manifests/params.pp:112:26 on node prod.maker.com
Dec 25 11:33:53 prod puppet-agent: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

File permissions are user nagios, group nagios:

```
[root@prod nagios] ls -l | grep check_puppet
total 164
-rw-r-----.    1 nagios nagios   469 Dec 25 05:59 check_puppet.cfg
```

Sample run:

```
[root@prod nagios] /usr/local/nagios/scripts/check_logs.pl -c /usr/local/nagios/custom/check_logs_puppetclient.cfg
puppet_err.log => OK;
```

Comment: There was no issue here, apart from misunderstanding on my part. The presence of seek file was causing "OK" on execution. Otherwise this is working fine and as per expected behavior. It does give error on first execution and "OK" on subsequent.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which version of plugin you are using, but according to official [documentation](https://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_logfiles/#format-of-a-configuration-file) there is no directive `reg_exp` and `file_name`.
I think you should use `criticalpatterns`, something like this:

```
$seek_file_template='/var/log/puppet/$log_file.puppet-agent.check_log.seek';

@log_files =
  (
    {
      'logfile'    => '/var/log/puppet/error.log',
      'criticalpatterns'  => ['Could not send report:', 'Could not retrieve file metadata for ', 'Could not retrieve catalog from remote server', 'Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run', 'Error 500 on SERVER:'],
    },
  );
```

Comment: This is the version used by me.
`check_logs.pl v$Revision: 1.1 $  (nagios-plugins 1.4.16)`. The file does not support any critical patterns as advised.

Comment: I tried using the suggestion I am getting errors such as

`Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at ./check_logs.pl line 66.
Use of uninitialized value $fbasename in substitution (s///) at ./check_logs.pl line 69.
Use of uninitialized value in -r at ./check_logs.pl line 71.`

On checking the script it is pattern mismatch at those lines.

Comment: @user6863772 I would suggest you to use improved and working version of that plugin along with my config suggestion. 
https://labs.consol.de/nagios/check_logfiles/#download

Comment: Sure I will try that and let you know how it goes.